# Can you sell apps made with Google App Inventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I read that Google App Inventor went live, not just invitation today.  If I make an app with Google App Inventor is there some way I can sell it?  Thanks.

edit:  when you create something you do you keep it on your computer like an executable?  I don't have android phone but I thought I could still make something for it. (seems to be answered by faq Can you share project code with other App Inventor users?)

Answer (score 4):

Some folks have got App Inventor apps into the Market. They had to mess with the apk.

The apk does not have some of what the Market requires.

It's a complied apk that works with a Scheme engine on the phone.

I'm a moderator on their forums. Come ask there. It's a friendly bunch.
(well most of us. I sometimes slip ;-))

Gary
http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/forum/
http://www.theairepository.info/

Comment: Please provide some direct links/excerpts to the problem/approach in particular.

Comment: only if it is ok with the powers that be here. We tried before and the posts ...went away... and I do not want to impose. I am shooting for a rep of 1500 so I can add info. Should take about 9 years :-)

Answer (score 2):

From the [faq](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/userfaq.html):

> Currently there are technical
>   limitations preventing an App Inventor
>   app from being uploaded to the Android
>   Market, but we are actively working to
>   resolve this.

It's probably due to the fact that it doesn't generate Java source code. Doesn't mean that you can't use other app markets though...

Comment: So you get the app on your computer to do with what you want like sell it somewhere else?

Comment: You probably get a compiled APK, which technically is all you need to distribute your app. You'll have to research what android app markets out there will accept that.

Answer (score 1):

If you google apptomarket you will find a program that will edit the apk for you. You enter your certificate details and then you change the settings in the apk like the version number, change the app name, make it resizeable, icons, and orientation. Then you package it for the android market. I have used it already and haven't had any complaints yet. It is easy to use and its free. What more could you want.... apart from an iphone version of the app inventor but me thinks that Steve Jobs would hunt me down for just thinking of such blasphemy, oh well.